# Diffrent amount of in game currency per country in app purcheses

Tags: android, ios, google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store

Can I give players different amount of in game currency depending on the country? Doesn't prohibit such thing, any of the store regulations? (AppStore or GooglePlay) For example in US the iap costs $0.99 and gives 100 points, in Canada the same tier costs CA$1.99 which would give the player ~130 points. (taking that $1 is CA$1.32) Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set different prices for different countries.